# Paperclip skip style on first save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

This is my code:

```
:styles => lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.define_styles }

def define_styles 
    return_styles = Hash.new

    case self.imageable_type

    when "Admin::ProductDetail"
      return_styles[:thumb] = "70x60>"
      return_styles[:front] = "450x400>"
    else

    end

    return_styles
end
```

The problem is that when I first upload the image, it dont use the styles... only after I reupload the image, so it is only creating the default style, not the **:thumb** or **:front** in the first upload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback `before_post_process`

```
:styles => lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.define_styles }

before_post_process :skip_on_create

def skip_on_create
  !new_record?
end
```

When this callback returns false, the post processing step will be halted

Documentation [here](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip#Events)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. And this is the right way to it, `reprocess` is for different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code and it works now.

```
after_create :reprocess

def reprocess
  self.image.reprocess!
end
```

But I don't know if it's the right way to do it.